# JavaScript 2D collision anomaly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experimenting with HTML5 canvas scripting in JavaScript and am having an issue with 2D collision detection. I'm basically checking the coordinates of the "player" against the coordinates of a box I've placed on screen but a strange result is occurring. I know why it's happening, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Some of my code:

```
function Arc()
{
    // Coordinates.
    this.x = 540 / 2;
    this.y = 0;

    // Radius
    this.r = 50;

    // Gravity / velicoty.
    this.g = 3;
    this.vy = 15;

    // Bounce.
    this.b = -0;

    this.speed = 20;
    this.max_speed = 20;

    this.friction = 0.03444;
}

Arc.prototype.collision = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < game.sprites.length; i++)
    {
        if
        (
            // If the right side of the player is greater than the left side of the object.
            this.x + this.r > game.sprites[i].x &&

            // If the bottom of the player is greater than (meaning lower than) the top of the object.
            this.y + this.r > game.sprites[i].y &&

            // If the left side of the player is greater than the right side of the object.
            this.x - this.r < game.sprites[i].x + game.sprites[i].w &&

            // if the top of the player is greater than (meaning lower than) the bottom of the object.
            this.y - this.r < game.sprites[i].y + game.sprites[i].h
        )
        {
            this.y = game.sprites[i].y - this.r;
            this.vy *= this.b;

        }
    }
}
```

The anomaly is that when I move the player sprite over the left or right of the box, it jumps upwards on the Y-axis because the logical check above is always true. Obviously this is unexpected because the sprite should only interact with the top of the box if a jump has occurred.

Note: I'm **not** looking for a solution that adds collision to the sides of the box only (that's very simple). Rather, I'm looking for the solution that allows for collision on all sides of the box (including the top) in the same way it currently works but without the anomaly where the sprite suddenly jumps on top of the box upon touching it.

I've reproduced my entire project on JSFiddle for the purposes of demonstration (keys a, d and space bar): http://jsfiddle.net/h5Fun/

Comment: what is the expected behavior? instead of moving the circle up it should just stop moving and sit next to the box?

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying. Indeed, the sprite should be stopped and maybe repelled in the opposite direction, not forced to move up on the Y-axis when it is not warranted. The only time the circle should interact with the top of the box is when the user jumps on top of the box.

Comment: @user3005790 I only see one collision function, and you're setting the `y`, not the `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is what you want, it solves the problem:

```
this.x = game.sprites[i].x + 150;
this.vx *= this.b;
```

The issue was you were setting the incorrect component upon collision. If you want the circle to stop when it hits the rectangle, not go on top of it, then use `x`, not `y`.

`150` is the size of the rectangle. This means it will stop at the right side of the sprite. The bouncing is already there due to modifying the velocity (`this.vx`).

Comment: I've tried the code but it doesn't produce correct results on my side. Basically I can easily make the circle stop when it hits the X-axis, but I'm looking for all-around collision detection. Just setting the code to detect the X coordinate stops the circle across the entirety of the Y-axis too, so jumping over the square becomes impossible. Also the `this.vx` in my source is currently unused :-)

Comment: @user3005790 Well I answered your question, but correct collision detection is a whole 'nother ballpark.